# Calling javascript form php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am having a form inside a php script. I am doing the validation using javascript.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("servername","login","passsword");
if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("dbadminatms", $con);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comments']))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO feedback_comments (posted_by, email, comments_text, comment_date)
        VALUES
    ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[comments]',NOW())";
    $emailID = $_POST['email'];
    $postedBy = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['comments'];

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        mail( "aaa@bbb.coml.com", "Subject: Comments", $message, "From: $emailID\r\n $postedBy" );
    }
}
    else
{

echo '


<form action="contactus.php" method="POST" id="feedback" onsubmit="javascript:return validate("feedback","name","email","comments");">

                <p id="errorMsg">All fields are required</p>

                <label for="name" class="label" id="nameLabel">Your name: </label><input id="name" type="text" size="30"  name="name" class="field"/>
                <br /><br />
                <label for="email" class="label" id="emailLabel">Your Email id: </label><input id="email" type="text" size="30"  name="email" class="field"/>
                <br /><br />

                    <label for="comments" class="label" id="commentsLabel">Comments:</label>
                  <div id="commentsSection">
                    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="ui-corner-all" cols="9" rows="5" tabindex="140"></textarea>
                  </div>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>&nbsp;<input type="reset" /></p>

        </form>';
}

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Everrything's is working fine but I can't validate the form using javascript.

Comment: it's impossible to call javascript form php but from HTML only. You have to figure it out first of all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant excerpt is:

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validate("feedback","name","email","comments");"
```

Two things:

1. Your use of double quotes within the attribute will end it prematurely (the browser will only see `onsubmit="javascript:return validate("`, which is invalid and will be tossed by the JavaScript interpreter). Use single quotes instead within the attribute value:

   ```
   onsubmit="javascript:return validate('feedback','name','email','comments');"
   ```
2. Do you actually have a JavaScript function called `validate` that's included in the page somewhere, either directly or via an external JavaScript file?

Separately, note that if you use `onsubmit`, you don't use `javascript:` at the beginning, just:

```
onsubmit="return validate('feedback','name','email','comments');"
```

The `javascript:` pseudo-protocol is only used where the HTML would normally contain a link, as with the `href` attribute of anchors. `onsubmit` and similar don't accept links, just JavaScript code, so you don't use it. (It's largely harmless if you do, because coincidentally it looks like a *label* in JavaScript, and so the code parses okay and runs. But it's wrong.)

---

**Off-topic, but important**: **NEVER** rely on client-side validation; client-side validation is *purely* a user experience improvement exercise (helping people send you things you'll accept), **never** a replacement for server-side validation. Your PHP code as quoted is wide open to SQL injection (or even innocent issues — what happens if there's a `'` in one of the fields, for instance?). Search for "SQL Injection PHP" to find lots of way so correctly process submitted data.

Comment: Thanks. But my echo statement is in single quotes and onsubmit attribute in double quotes. Now how am I suppose to use quotes for parameters of validate functions.

Comment: @dilip: You can escape the single quotes in PHP using the backslash: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 2):

Plus good practice states that you should sanitize your inputs, never rely only on JS validation, but also do it serverside, and never EVER EEEEEEVER use $_POST['whatever'] directly in your query, its damn dangerous, process the input and try to save yourself from xss, and mostly sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify javascriptin onsubmit:

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validate("feedback","name","email","comments")"
```

instead do this:

```
onsubmit="return validate("feedback","name","email","comments")"
```

and I hope you are putting proper escape charaters for the strings. Use this instead:

```
onsubmit="return validate(\"feedback\",\"name\",\"email\",\"comments\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery is better.

[jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: You should post this as a comment, it's not an answer to the question(you'll be able to leave comments with 50 reputation's points)

Comment: Please don't post jQuery answers to JavaScript questions.

Comment: And by the way, JQuery validation is not better, it's just a plugin using javascript. You can do the same and even better using plain javascript.